# Trouble with sending data through Serial2 in esp32

Tags: esp32, rs485

I need to send hex data from esp32wroom to a relay module. The communication is via RS485. The RS485 module used in SN75H12VD.The Rx and Tx pins are 16 and 17 of esp32. The enable pin is connected to pin 4. I have made the enable pin HIGH. I tried to use hardwareserial. Used a serial terminal to check whether the data is being sent. But nothing is getting printed. I also tried Serial2. But no luck. Please find my code below. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

```
#include<Arduino.h>

#include <HardwareSerial.h>

#define RXD2 16

#define TXD2 17

#define enable_pin 4


HardwareSerial mySer(2);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("hi");

  mySer.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);

  pinMode(RXD2, INPUT);

  pinMode(TXD2, OUTPUT); 
  
  pinMode(enable_pin, OUTPUT);

  delay(10); 

  digitalWrite(enable_pin, HIGH);

}

void loop() 

{

  if (!mySer) 

  { // If the object did not initialize, then its configuration is invalid

    Serial.println("Invalid pin configuration, check config");

    while (1) { // Don't continue with invalid configuration

        delay (1000);

      }

  }

  else {

  Serial.println("hello");

  mySer.println("hey");

  mySer.write(0x13);

  mySer.write(0x01);

  mySer.write(0x03);

  mySer.write(0x40);

  mySer.write(0x02);

  mySer.write(0x01);

  mySer.write(0x00);

  mySer.write(0xC9);

  mySer.write(0x80);

  mySer.write(0x0A);

  delay(2000);

  mySer.write(0x13);

  mySer.write(0x01);

  mySer.write(0x03);

  mySer.write(0x40);

  mySer.write(0x02);

  mySer.write(0x00);

  mySer.write(0x00);

  mySer.write(0xC8);

  mySer.write(0x10);

  mySer.write(0x0A);

  delay(2000);`enter code here`

  }
}
```

Comment: Take out the `pinMode()` calls for `RXD2` and `TXD2` and try it again.

Comment: I took out the pinMode() calls. But still nothing is getting printed on the serial terminal

Comment: It would be great if someone could help me!